# BeautifulSoup and python: iteration through table does not work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been working on rewriting some old code I wrote years ago, now I've been running into issues:

I'm trying to extract information from a table on this site: https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html and put it into a database. The problem I'm facing is that when I run it, it keeps going over the same row. I've been trying a variety of solutions, but I cannot wrap my head around the issue.
When I run the code, I get:

```
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/murphyjeddidiahlast.html
--- retrieving statement 584  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 584 Murphy , Jeddidiah  ---
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/murphyjeddidiahlast.html
--- retrieving statement 584  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 584 Murphy , Jeddidiah  ---
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/murphyjeddidiahlast.html
--- retrieving statement 584  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 584 Murphy , Jeddidiah  ---
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/murphyjeddidiahlast.html
--- retrieving statement 584  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 584 Murphy , Jeddidiah  ---
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/murphyjeddidiahlast.html
```

It should obviously decrement during retrieving the information, but it keeps reading the same information over and over again.
This is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3  #warning: using charset 65001 by typing in cmd "chcp 65001" Only when showing last statements on screen.
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
import urllib
import urllib3

Titles = []
conn = sqlite3.connect('Deathrow.sqlite')
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()
conn.text_factory = str
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Inmates")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Inmates (id integer primary key, Execution text, Lastname text, Firstname text, TDCJNumber text, Age integer, Date text, Race text, County text, Laststatement text)")
conn.commit()
url='https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html'
data = requests.get(url,verify = False).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': "tdcj_table indent"})
headers = table.find_all("th")
for header in headers:
    Title = header.text
    Titles.append(Title)
rows = table.find_all('tr')
UrlLastStatement= "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/"
data = table.find_all('td')
#foreach row in rows [1:]:
for row in rows:
        #try:
        ExecutionID= str(data[0].get_text())
        Lastname = str(data[3].get_text())
        Firstname = str(data[4].get_text())
        TDJC = str(data[5].get_text())
        Age = str(data[6].get_text())
        Date = str(data[7].get_text())
        Race = str(data[8].get_text())
        County = str(data[9].get_text())
        print ("--- retrieving execution data for execution ID",ExecutionID,Lastname,",",Firstname," ---")
        LastStatementLinks = table.find_all("a", href=True)
        LastStatementLink = LastStatementLinks[1].get("href")
        Urlcomplete = UrlLastStatement + LastStatementLink
        print (Urlcomplete)
        r = requests.get(Urlcomplete,verify = False)
        #print(r)
        print ("--- retrieving statement", ExecutionID," ---")
        document = urllib.request.urlopen(Urlcomplete)
        html = document.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        pattern = re.compile("Last Statement:") 
        statement = soup.find(string=pattern).findNext('p').contents[0]
        statement = str(statement)
        statement = statement.lstrip(' ')
        statement = statement.rstrip(' ')
        statement = statement.replace("<span class=", "")
        statement = statement.replace("</span>", "")
        statement = statement.replace('"', "")
        statement = statement.replace("text_italic>", "")
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Inmates (Execution, Lastname, Firstname, TDCJNumber, Age, Date, Race, County, Laststatement) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", (str(ExecutionID), str(Firstname), str(Lastname), str(TDJC), str(Age), str(Date), str(Race), str(County), str(statement), ))
            #continue
    #except Exception:
        #print ("A non fatal error has occured, proceeding...")
        #continue

conn.commit()
conn.close()
print ("Retrieval complete. Open deathrow.sqlite to see the data. Execute gword.py to create the wordcloud.")
```

I first want to resolve this issues before I'll continue to refine the other parts of the code. Is this an issue with my for-loop?

**UPDATE**: thanks for the answers to my questions. I got it working and update my code. Now I've been running in just one more issue:
The links to the statements of 3 inmates are wrong. For inmate 545 the link is "/death_row/dr_info/cardenasrubenlast.html" when it should be "/dr_info/cardenasrubenlast.html". This causes my program not to retrieve the last statements of 3 inmates.

I've updated my code (see below) and tried to fix it with if statements where the variable linkLS should take a different URL, but I'm having a strange output:

```
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/shoreanthonylast.html
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 545 Cardenas , Ruben  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 544 Pruett , Robert  ---
--- retrieving execution data for execution ID 543 Preyor , Taichin  ---
--- retrieving statement 543  ---
https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/preyortaichinlast.html
```

See my code below. How can I pass the correct URL to linkLS so it gets the correct statement for the correct inmate?

```
import sqlite3
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
import urllib
import urllib3
import ssl
from datetime import datetime

ExecutionID= None
linkLS = None
conn = sqlite3.connect('Deathrow.sqlite')
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()
conn.text_factory = str
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Inmates")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Inmates (id integer primary key, Execution text, Lastname text, Firstname text, TDCJNumber text, Age integer, Date text, Race text, County text, Laststatement text, LastStatementURL text, InmateInformation, text)")
conn.commit()
url='https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html'
data = requests.get(url,verify = False).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': "tdcj_table indent"})
headers = table.find_all("th")
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in table.find_all("tr") [1:]:
        
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        ExecutionID= str(cells[0].get_text())
        InmateInformation = 'https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/' + cells[1].a['href']
        linkLS = 'https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/' + cells[2].a['href']
        Lastname = str(cells[3].get_text())
        Firstname = str(cells[4].get_text())
        TDJC = str(cells[5].get_text())
        Age = int(cells[6].get_text())
        Date = (cells[7].get_text())
        Date = datetime.strptime(Date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
        Race = str(cells[8].get_text())
        County = str(cells[9].get_text())
        print ("--- retrieving execution data for execution ID",ExecutionID,Lastname,",",Firstname," ---")
        if ExecutionID == "545":
            linkLS == "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/cardenasrubenlast.html"
        elif ExecutionID == "544":
            linkLS == "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/pruettrobertlast.html"
        elif ExecutionID == "552":
            linkLS =="https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_info/no_last_statement.html"
        else:
            r = requests.get(linkLS,verify = False)
            print ("--- retrieving statement", ExecutionID," ---")
            print (linkLS)
            document = urllib.request.urlopen(linkLS)
            html = document.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
            pattern = re.compile("Last Statement:")
            try:
                statement = soup.find(string=pattern).findNext('p').contents[0]
                statement = str(statement)
                statement = statement.lstrip(' ')
                statement = statement.rstrip(' ')
                statement = statement.replace("<span class=", "")
                statement = statement.replace("</span>", "")
                statement = statement.replace('"', "")
                statement = statement.replace("text_italic>", "")
            except Exception:
                    print("An error has occured while retrieving the statement. Proceeding...")
                    statement = ""
                    continue

        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Inmates (Execution, Lastname, Firstname, TDCJNumber, Age, Date, Race, County, Laststatement, LastStatementURL, InmateInformation) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", (str(ExecutionID), str(Firstname), str(Lastname), str(TDJC), int(Age), str(Date), str(Race), str(County), str(statement), str(linkLS), str(InmateInformation)))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print ("Retrieval complete. Open deathrow.sqlite to see the data. Execute gword.py to create the wordcloud.")
```

Comment: You read `data` once, before the loop starts.  You never change it, so you're reading the first row over and over and over and over.  You need to do `data = row.find_all('td')` INSIDE the loop.

Comment: You should open a new question, not update this one with new topics.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting anything from the current `row` of the iteration, you use the same indexes of `data`. Change it so that `data` is the `td` elements in each row.

```
for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    # rest of your loop code here
```

Answer (score 0):

This site use ssl. You can load the html with pandas `read_html()` and write `to_sql()` it to **SQLite3** with this few lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from unicodedata import normalize

import ssl
# for ssl certificate
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

import sqlite3
# Create the sqlite3 database
conn = sqlite3.connect("Deathrow.sqlite")

# scrap the table from html
df = pd.read_html('https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html')

# Write the table
df[0].to_sql('Inmates', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
conn.close()
```

Output in [DB Browser for SQL](https://sqlitebrowser.org/):
[image]